# Inequality involve derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given function $f: (-\infty,+\infty) \to [0,+\infty)$ that its third derivative is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$ and: $$\underset{x\in\mathbb{R}}{\mathrm{max}}\left|f'''(x) \right|\le 1. $$
Prove that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we have:$$f''(x)\ge -\sqrt[3]{\frac{3}{2}f(x)}.$$

*My attempt: Firstly we have $f'''(x) \in [-1,1] \ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}.$

Suppost that there is $x_0$ that $f''(x_0) < -\sqrt[3]{\frac{3}{2}f(x_0)} \le 0.$

$\Rightarrow \exists \delta>0: f''(x) < 0 \  \forall x\in[x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]$ and $f$ is concave function on $[x_0-\delta,x_0+\theta]$ but it is hard for me to continue the solution.

Another attempt: my using Taylor series for $f(x)$ at $x_0$:

$$f(x)=f(x_0)+(x-x_0)f'(x_0)+\dfrac{(x-x_0)^2}{2}f''(x_0)+\dfrac{(x-x_0)^3}{6}f'''(\theta x)$$

$$\Rightarrow 0\le f(x) <f(x_0)+(x-x_0)f'(x_0) +\dfrac{1}{6}(x-x_0)^3f'''(\theta x) \ (*) $$

Cause third-degree polynomial change sign in $\mathbb{R}$, I try to take $x\to \infty$ to give the contradiction but I am stuck with the sign of $f'''(\theta x)$.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please include some personal work, like how you’ve tried to attempt the question yourself.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of my attempt in this post. I will post it again with my attempt.

Comment: @ana  No need for reposting, you can edit the present post.